# Injecting HTML Special Characters from DE into HTML via AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

The problem is that my special characters are breaking the way the HTML renders not only in SFMC Email Studio but also once the email is sent, however when I inspect the source there doesn't seem to be an issue. I can only assume this is some weird interaction between AmpScript and HTML.

Code Snippet (Inside HTML Email)

```
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">
  SET @stack_name_a = Concat("Stack&#160;Jordan&#160;Limited&#65279;.")
  SET @stack_address_a = Concat("P<span></span>O&#160;Box&#160;1231,&#160;Ne<span></span>wYork,&#160;NY&#160;1<span></span>12&#160;123&#160;U<span></span>SA")
  SET @stack_name_b = Concat("2&#160;Stack&#160;Jordan&#160;Limited&#65279;.")
  SET @stack_address_b = Concat("P<span></span>O&#160;Box&#160;1231,&#160;Ne<span></span>wYork,&#160;NY&#160;1<span></span>12&#160;123&#160;U<span></span>SA")
  SET @website = Concat("stackoverflow&#65279;.com")
</script>

<p style="font-size: 12px; color: #666666; line-height: 150%;">
 I am here to test this message because it does not properly format, this message is a by <span dir="ltr" style="direction:ltr; white-space: nowrap;">%%=v(@stack_name_a)=%%</span>, for <a href="" style="direction: ltr; color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">%%=v(@website)=%%</a> and i am glad this is working, my address is <span dir="ltr" style="direction:ltr; white-space: nowrap;">%%=v(@stack_address_a)=%%</span>. On the other hand, it does seem to break randomly, so i am sending another message by <span dir="ltr" style="direction:ltr; white-space: nowrap;">%%=v(@stack_name_b)=%%</span>, for <a href="" style="direction: ltr; color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">%%=v(@website)=%%</a> and i really hope it breaks for demo purposes, <span dir="ltr" style="direction:ltr; white-space: nowrap;">%%=v(@stack_address_b)=%%</span>.</p>
```

**Result:**
I am here to test this message because it does not properly format, this message is a by Stack Jordan Limited., for stackoverflow.com and i am glad this is working, my address is PO Box 1231, NewYork, NY 112 123 USA. On the other hand, it does seem to break randomly, so i am sending another message by 2 Stack Jordan Limited., for stackoverflow.com and i really hope it breaks for demo purposes, P O Box 1231, NewYork, NY 112 123 USA.

**The Problem:**
`P O Box 1231, NewYork, NY 112 123 USA` was rendered incorrectly, `PO` should be together. I am assuming that some of the special characters I am using are breaking the interaction between AMP Script and HTML.

So far I have tried to use `v`, `TreatAsContent` and `Concat`. I can't figure out how to resolve this. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue I think. Email Studio does not use proper HTML rules for emails, in fact I am unsure which rules it is using. However as of HTMlL 4.0.1 you can have both `span` tag inside of `a` tag and vice versa.

In salesforce email studio, you **must** apparently use `span` tag before an `a` tag, if you want to have more inline `span` tags.

It would be nice to know why SFMC has this awkward interaction but I couldn't find any relevant documentation on it.